# Using xargs arguments multiple times in the same command

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I have a script that loops through hundreds of lines and executes a java command for each line. To run it in parallel, I'm using xargs. I was able to parallelize the execution. However, my formatting of the data has affected a bit.

```
 cat test.txt | xargs --max-procs=10 --max-args=6 -I '{}' kafka-run-class '{}' | column -t | tr -s ' ' , | sed -e "s/^/$(date '+%F %T'),Test,**'{}'**,/g"
```

I want the argument from xargs to be used in sed! Is that possible?

Output from kafka-run-class is below.

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
Test1  0          15336084        15336084        0          consumer-1-e9ff70f4-01e4-4c69-9c92-c568319c0e95   /192.1.127.32                  consumer-1
```

The final output i'm expecting is below.

```
2019-02-14 17:18:13,Test,**'{}'**,Test1,0,15336084,15336084,0,consumer-1-e9ff70f4-01e4-4c69-9c92-c568319c0e95,/192.1.127.32,consumer-1
```

I was able to achieve this using for loop instead of xargs but that will mean the script runs slow.

Comment: What is the benchmark result of your for loop compared to other methods? Do you realse that `-I` negates `--max-args`? What is purpose of `column -t`? (It is negated by `tr`.)

Comment: I didn't know that `-I` negates `--max-args` !!! Thanks for the info. I'm using `column -t` just for formatting while debugging. The for loop is taking about 25-30min while xargs is finishing in <3min.

Comment: I tried something like this `xargs --max-procs=5 -I {} bash -c 'vConsumer="{}" ; kafka-run-class {} | grep -vE "TOPIC|sentry-conf|^$|Error" |sed -e "s/^/Test,${vConsumer},/g" ` This is giving me the desired result and some performance improvement than for loop. However the sed substitution for few lines is errorsum!  While i'm expecting below, `Test,TestGroup,Test_Topic 3 `, i'm getting `roup,Test_Topic 3 `

Comment: If you have multiple processes writing to stdout simultaneously, you need to ensure they do so atomically, oherwise output can get mixed up.